# Visual Studio Compiled code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any way to see the compiled code output from the visual studio itself. I know that we can use some reflector software and see the code. but i just want to see the compiler code while coding in the visual studio. so i can decide what is the best coding approach for certain task by looking at the output code.

***Note: Support for C# would be enough for me.***

**Updated:**

---

I want to see Intermediate Language(IL) output of the C# code.

Comment: Any specific language/compiler output?

Comment: What do you mean by compiled code? Machine code, code after preprocessing, something else?

Comment: Support for C# would be enough for me

Comment: When you say C# and compiled code, do you mean the IL, or the native code that gets jitted off the IL?

Comment: @Oded: I mean IL code output

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you are not talking about .NET languages (C#, VB.NET, F# etc...), you can use the [disassembly window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3cwf295.aspx):

> The Disassembly window shows assembly code corresponding to the instructions created by the compiler. If you are debugging managed code, these assembly instructions correspond to the native code created by the Just-in-Time (JIT) compiler, not the Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) generated by the Visual Studio compiler.

---

If, however, you are talking about viewing IL for .NET languages - [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) can show it to you, as will most disassemblers (such as Reflector). Many of these will show you their C# / VB.NET interpretation of the IL by default, but you can *always* view the IL directly.

Some of these also have Visual Studio add-ons/extensions that allow you to see the disassembly directly in Visual Studio (Reflector and Resharper will both do this).

Comment: I installed Reflector 8 extension to Visual Studio 2013 Professional, but it doesn't show CIL code. It shows C# code of imported packets. Maybe it is possible to display CIL code directly in Visual Studio, but I can't find that option?

Comment: Is there a way to see what _syntactic sugar_ looks like once compiled? For example: `var n = 1` would be compiled into `int n = 1` or `obj?.prop` complied into `if (obj != null) ? obj.prop : null`

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien - yes, by using the tools I have mentioned in my answer.